# How to delete surplus lines after end of lines of text?

Tags: notepad++

[image]

I'm trying to build some macros, and I need the lines of text to be EXACT, for some reason, notepad appends a space at the end, and I can't get rid of it...

I have textFX with notepad++ but I can also use netbeans or brackets.

Problem is I don't know how to explain this, so can't google it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't a space, it is the new line character. This (or these, denpends on your OS) character(s) tell NPP and any other program "Hey, here you need to start a new line!"

Notepad++ represents this character by a space when it is selected, which helps you see that you have a new line selected instead of no selection.

Open your file in Windows Notepad and you won't see any space at the end of the lines.

More info: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline

Comment: How do I delete that space? Is it possible? I need to copy the word, not the word + a space

Comment: Copying the line won't copy the space because there is *no* space. This new line character is what tells your programs (including macros) that it is another line. If you remove it, your three first lines will become something like `AccelerateActivelloAscent` - i.e. no more line breaks.

Comment: Hi Nathan, yes you are right, the macro didn't work for another reason, not that, so it confused me!

Comment: You're welcome. I hope you can solve your problem!